# What‘s the difference between "identifier" and "identifierName" in ECMAScript 2020？

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2020

https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-IdentifierName
I don't undestand well the difference between "identifier" and "identifierName" in ECMAScript 2020.

Comment: Can you quote a short snippet of the relevant parts here…?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in the Documentation linked by your self, in one concise sentence:

> The syntactic grammar defines Identifier as an IdentifierName that is not a ReservedWord.

Answer (score 0):

In the ECMAScript specification, the *lexical* grammar doesn't 'know' anything about reserved words; any word-like thing is recognized as an IdentifierName. It's then up to the *syntactic* level to decide how to deal with an IdentifierName. If an IdentifierName doesn't match the ReservedWord production, then it qualifies as an Identifier, and (to a first approximation) can be used in all the places you'd expect an identifier. (The complete rules are somewhat complicated: see [12.6.2 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words) for a summary.)